# Protractor recursive function error: Function not defined

Tags: javascript, function, recursion, promise, protractor

I am trying to get elements from several pages, going through the pages and collecting those elements recursively.
However I get an error stating that the function I am calling is not defined, however it should be defined.
See the script bellow:

```
getAllComponents() {
return element
   .all(by.css('css_selector')).map((el) => {
   return el.getText();
})
.then((array) => {
   element(by.css('next_page_Button_Css_Selector')).isPresent()
   .then((present) => {
     if(present){
        element(by.css(next_page_button_css_selector)).click();
        return array.concat(getAllComponents()); //RECURSIVE CALL NOT WORKING
      } else{
          return array;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

What is my error(s)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a `function` keyword missing from the first line of this code? Or is there some other context which is missing (and probably the cause of the problem)

Comment: Sorry yes, I have to specify that the code above is within a class. I have other methods as well working fine. It's just this method called recursively that I am not able to run successfully.

Comment: If it's within a class, you forgot to add the `this` keyword to the method invocation. Should be `array.concat(this.getAllComponents())`.

Comment: I was definitely missing the 'this' keyword, thanks!